# Why php do not print all content of field text type

Tags: php, text, field

I create a slq table (postgres db) and i want to print all value of the field 'notes' but php print only first word of this value.

```
$name=trim($_POST['name']);


//select


if(!$query = @pg_query($conn,"SELECT notes FROM customer WHERE customer.name = '$name' "))
die("Errore nella query: " . pg_last_error($conn));


//print the content of field 'notes'


while($row = pg_fetch_array($query))
{

echo "<li>Notes: <input type=\"text\" placeholder=\"insert text\" id=\"note\" value=".$row['note']."></li>";    

}
```

if the value of my field notes is 'lorem ipsum dixit'

php print only 'lorem' cutting off 'ipsum dixit'

Why?

---

i find the solution, i replace

`echo "<li>Notes: <input type=\"text\" placeholder=\"insert text\" id=\"note\" value=".$row['note']."></li>";`

with

`<li>Note: <input type="text" placeholder="inserisci testo" id="note" value=" <?php echo $row['note'] ?>"></li>`

thank you everyone

Comment: Are your sure, that in DB record content "lorem ipsum dixit" ? Try execute this `var_dump($row);`

Comment: You still need to html-encode the string, since it could contain a doublequote - in PHP this can be done by functions htmlentities() or htmlspecialchars()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would also replace `echo "$row['notes']";` by `echo $row['notes'];`

Comment: basically, i don't see any reason for using the double quotes when you just want to echo out the contents of the cell

Answer (score 1):

You get something like

```
 <input ... value=lorem ipsum>
```

which should be

```
 <input ... value="lorem ipsum">
```

Answer (score 0):

BTW, there is no need of quotes, it should be `echo $row['notes'];`

Comment: Both variants are right. But with no double quotes is prefer.

Answer (score -1):

Because you're fetching an array, not an associative array, try using the mysql_fetch_assoc function and it should give you the behavior you're looking for.

Comment: Not write! Firstly not mysql_fetch_assoc, here is pgsql. And second array contant and assoc array too!

Comment: the problem is not the function. if print the result in this way echo "$row['notes']";   print all 'lorem ipsum dixit', but if i print the $row['notes'] in the input text hmtl field the text is cut off . example echo "<li>Notes: <input type=\"text\" placeholder=\"insert text\" id=\"note\" value=".$row['note']."></li>"; in this way print only 'lorem' why?

Comment: i DaOgre i try with same function for postgres but do not function if print the value in the input text field

Comment: @Antonio see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759153/why-php-do-not-print-all-content-of-field-text-type/5759694#5759694